# Color error by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pattern

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,caption,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
%\usepackage{fullpage,varwidth}

\tikzset{transform shape}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]\vspace*{5pt}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    % \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!30] (-7,-5) grid (7,5);
    \begin{scope}
    \draw[clip] (-4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \filldraw[thick, pattern color=gray!90, pattern=vertical lines] (-6,0) -- (-2,0) --(-2,5) -- (-6,5)--cycle;
    \filldraw[thick, pattern color=gray!90, pattern=horizontal lines] (-6,0) -- (-2,0) --(-2,-5) -- (-6,-5)--cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick] (-4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \draw[thick] (4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (6,0);
    \node at (-4,4) {{\Huge \boldmath $C$}};
    \node at (-4,-4) {{\Huge \boldmath $\bar {C \rule{0pt}{18pt}}$}};
    \node at (4,4) {{\Huge \boldmath $D$}};
    \node at (4,-4) {{\Huge \boldmath $\bar {D \rule{0pt}{18pt}}$}};
    \filldraw[pattern color=gray!90, pattern=vertical lines] (3.5,1) to[out=180, in=180] (4,2)
    to[out=0,in=0] (4.5,.7)
    to[out=180, in=45] (4,.4)
    to[out=180,in=0] cycle
    ;
    \draw[dashed] (-3.75,4.97) -- (4,2);
    \draw[dashed] (-2,0) -- (4,.4);
    \filldraw[pattern color=gray!90, pattern=horizontal lines] (4,-1) to[out=0,in=180] (4.5,-1.5)
    to[out=0,in=0] (4.5,-2)
    to[out=180,in=45] (4,-2.5)
    to[out=225,in=180,looseness=1.5] cycle
    ;
    \draw[dashed] (-2,0) -- (4,-1);
    \draw[dashed] (-3.8,-4.97) -- (3.85,-2.6);
    \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) node[pos=.5,above] {\LARGE $f$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,-2) -- (1.5,-2) node[pos=.5,below] {\LARGE $f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A schematic illustration of a reduction between two classification problems.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It works fine, but the vertical and horizontal line color shows as CMYK combination, but it should show only black, reference image is below:

[image]

If I check the rule color, then it shows the Gray is a mixture of CMYK value, refer the below image for clarification:

[image]

But it should shows only Black value, please suggest...

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by CMYK combination? For me, your code generates a grayscale image.

Comment: I can't see in your code where the red circles come from, should give a grayscale image as @Texnician mentioned.

Comment: @TeXnician now I edited my post, hope now it is clear...

Comment: Your added picture does not make sense. Do you want to set the color profile of the document, so that it is only grayscale?

Comment: @DRi red circle was made by me for to point out the error...

Comment: @TeXnician Yes, only grayscale should be there in the image...

Comment: I do not refer to the image, but to the document. If you check with an external tool then you will always be able to separate out RGB or CMYK values (regardless of the color, even for black). But if you want to have a document that is only grayscale to such a program you need to choose a color profile that turns your whole document grayscale and let the external program validate your colors *using that profile*. Otherwise the measurement does not tell you anything.

Comment: I think you are out of luck for the moment. `pgf` only supports patterns in RGB. So even though in your document you are specifying a grey colour, it comes out as RGB in the PDF. This then separates out across all four plates. I recently fixed the analogous issue with shadings in my `pgf-cmykshadings` package. Perhaps I could look to fixing things for patterns as well.

Comment: You can see the effect more clearly if you change you change all your colours everywhere to CMYK cyan. You'll notice the patterns come out in RGB :(

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks for your reply and expects the same to be fix in the next version of the package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to work around this without having to add support for CMYK/gray uncoloured patterns.

You can declare an *inherently coloured* pattern which includes the colour in its definition. These are not restricted to RGB, so you can create one that only appears on your black separation.

In the MWE below I have declared two new patterns (`gray vertical lines` and `gray horizontal lines`). The definition is the same as for `vertical lines` and `horizontal lines` except that a stroke colour is included and they are declared using `\pgfdeclarepatterninherentlycolored` instead of `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly`

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,caption,subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}

\tikzset{transform shape}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfdeclarepatterninherentlycolored{gray horizontal lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{3pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{gray!90}
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{100pt}{0.5pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\pgfdeclarepatterninherentlycolored{gray vertical lines}{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{1pt}{100pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{100pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{gray!90}
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0.5pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.5pt}{100pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]\vspace*{5pt}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    % \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!30] (-7,-5) grid (7,5);
    \begin{scope}
    \draw[clip] (-4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \filldraw[thick, pattern=gray vertical lines] (-6,0) -- (-2,0) --(-2,5) -- (-6,5)--cycle;
    \filldraw[thick, pattern=gray horizontal lines] (-6,0) -- (-2,0) --(-2,-5) -- (-6,-5)--cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[thick] (-4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \draw[thick] (4,0) ellipse (2 and 5);
    \draw[thick] (2,0) -- (6,0);
    \node at (-4,4) {{\Huge \boldmath $C$}};
    \node at (-4,-4) {{\Huge \boldmath $\bar {C \rule{0pt}{18pt}}$}};
    \node at (4,4) {{\Huge \boldmath $D$}};
    \node at (4,-4) {{\Huge \boldmath $\bar {D \rule{0pt}{18pt}}$}};
    \filldraw[pattern color=gray!90, pattern=vertical lines] (3.5,1) to[out=180, in=180] (4,2)
    to[out=0,in=0] (4.5,.7)
    to[out=180, in=45] (4,.4)
    to[out=180,in=0] cycle
    ;
    \draw[dashed] (-3.75,4.97) -- (4,2);
    \draw[dashed] (-2,0) -- (4,.4);
    \filldraw[pattern=gray horizontal lines] (4,-1) to[out=0,in=180] (4.5,-1.5)
    to[out=0,in=0] (4.5,-2)
    to[out=180,in=45] (4,-2.5)
    to[out=225,in=180,looseness=1.5] cycle
    ;
    \draw[dashed] (-2,0) -- (4,-1);
    \draw[dashed] (-3.8,-4.97) -- (3.85,-2.6);
    \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) node[pos=.5,above] {\LARGE $f$};
    \draw[thick, ->] (-1.5,-2) -- (1.5,-2) node[pos=.5,below] {\LARGE $f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A schematic illustration of a reduction between two classification problems.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't know if this works for sure, as I don't know how to check the color of individual elements without Acrobat PRO other than perusing the uncompressed PDF file and hoping I understanding the PDF spec correctly.

The uncompressed PDF file seems to produce colors correcly in the right places (e.g., `0 0 0 1` for `black`, `1 0 0 0` for `cyan` and so on). So I guess it sort of works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Either way it is a hack, necessitated by the fact that PGF only currently produces RGB patterns by default. In its current form it may also break other things. But it could form the basis of a proper solution.

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 % Only needed to open the PDF as text.
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter
% Patch \pgfutil@convertcolorspec to always use cmyk
% This is likely to have have side effects!
\def\pgfutil@convertcolorspec#1#2#3{\convertcolorspec{#1}{#2}{cmyk}}

% \pgf@set@fill@patternuncolored to use an extra argument
\def\pgf@set@fill@patternuncolored#1,#2,#3,#4\relax#5{%
  \pgfsys@setpatternuncolored{\csname pgf@pattern@name@#5\endcsname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

% Add the DeviceCMYK to the patterns resource.
\pgfutil@addpdfresource@colorspaces{ /pgfpcmyk [/Pattern /DeviceCMYK] }

% Set the uncolored pattern.
\def\pgfsys@setpatternuncolored#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \pgfsysprotocol@literal{/pgfpcmyk cs #2 #3 #4 #5/pgfpat#1\space scn}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \draw [pattern color=black, pattern=horizontal lines] 
    (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I think this does work