# Tikz - hatching introduces color in black/white picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, color, cmyk

I have a problem with the colors of my tikz diagrams.

My publisher told me, that the hatchings have residue color. Unfortunately, this is correct but not visible. Now, I have to remove these color traces but I don't know how.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns} 

\definecolor{myblack}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\draw[pattern = grid, pattern color = myblack] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,1); 

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

If I check the resulting pdf with ghostscript:

```
gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov <filename>.pdf
```

I get the output:

```
0.47000  0.47000  0.47000  0.59889 CMYK OK
```

I expected the first three numbers to be exactly zero. By removing the pattern command the values become zero.

Why does the pattern command introduces residue color and how can I remove the color?

Thanks!

**====== Update ======**

If I add my own pattern (I found the code somewhere here on tex.stackexchange), there is no color issue (I have no idea why...).
Add following code before "begin{document}" and change pattern name to "my north east lines".

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\LineSpace]{my north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace}{\LineSpace}}%
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}{\LineSpace + 0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother
\newdimen\LineSpace
\tikzset{
    line space/.code={\LineSpace=#1},
    line space=10pt
}
```

Comment: +1 we have had exactly this issue just a few weeks ago. A colleague worked out some postprocessing to eliminate the colour from the PDFs, and maybe they'll come on here and share that. However, I cannot fully explain why pgf is doing this, but the answer to the following post suggests to me that it is rather complex (as things with PDFs tend to be): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149144/tikz-patterns-and-cmyk-color-model/149831

Comment: Ok, by adding the modified code from your link the color issue is gone. So I can continue my work, but I think the question itself is still open. This might be the case, because I don't really understand the explanation in your linked answer^^ or in other words: Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: perhaps someone who knows about pgf and PDF can advise whether there is an easy fix, but my very vague belief (which could be completely wrong) of what is going on is that pgf is converting colours into RGB format, which is then converted back into CMYK in the PDF in a way that assumes full colour.  The solution we found was to put the PDF through some postprocessing to strip out all the colour, namely `gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray 
-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray  -sOutputFile="output.pdf"   input.pdf`

Comment: this postprocessing treatment doesn't change anything... the output of inkcov is the same

Comment: You're right... that's odd, because it manages to strip out colour in some other tikz figures where we had ostensibly the same issue...

Comment: I think this basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462123/color-error-by-using-tikz/462548. Does using an inherently coloured patter like in my answer solve your issue?

Comment: The problem is basically that the form only patterns from `tikz` only support RGB. No one has had the inclination to fix this yet because it's possible to use the inherently coloured patterns as a workaround. I added support for CMYK and Grayscale shadings and it's on my list to try and add CMYK and Grayscale pattern support sometime in the future.

Comment: @DavidPurton I guess the case for cmyk support is so that the pre-defined tikz patterns can be used (rather than re-defined with inherent colour). In my university's case, we have many different users producing PDF files which then have to go to a printer, so wide usability is an issue. I guess it would be easy enough to produce a set of "grayscale" patterns with inherently coloured patterns for people to use...

Comment: @rbrignall, yes I know it's far from ideal and it does give unexpected results at the moment. Last time I looked at this it wasn't quite as easy as I hoped :(.

Comment: @rbrignall, you can follow progress on this issue at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/405. It looks like Henri Menke has this feature planned for the next release! Though that looks like a while off yet.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting some links from the comments, the following workaround seems to resolve the issue: I'm recording it here really as a "temporary" solution for anyone else who comes along, and note that this is essentially the same code as in the question here: [Tikz patterns and cmyk color model](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149144/tikz-patterns-and-cmyk-color-model/149831)

It may well be that in other uses of pgf, the following code is not enough and something else needs to be done.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
% from pgfsys-pdftex.def
\def\pgfsys@setpatternuncolored#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \pgfsysprotocol@literal{/pgfpcmyk cs #2 #3 #4 #5 /pgfpat#1\space scn}%
}

\def\pgf@sys@pgf@resource@list@colorspaces{} % Empties all reference
                                % to RGB

\pgfutil@addpdfresource@colorspaces{ /pgfpcmyk [/Pattern /DeviceCMYK] }

% from pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
\def\pgf@set@fillpattern#1#2{%
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@pattern@name@#1}{%
    \pgferror{Undefined pattern `#1'}}
  {%
    \csname pgf@pattern@instantiate@#1\endcsname%
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgf@pattern@instantiate@#1\endcsname=\relax%
    \pgf@ifpatternisinherentlycolored{#1}{%
      \pgfsys@setpatterncolored{\csname pgf@pattern@name@#1\endcsname}%
    }{%
      \pgfutil@colorlet{pgf@tempcolor}{#2}%
      \pgfutil@ifundefined{applycolormixins}{}{\applycolormixins{pgf@tempcolor}}%
      \pgfutil@extractcolorspec{pgf@tempcolor}{\pgf@tempcolor}%
      % Modified (hum)
      \expandafter\pgfutil@convertcolorspec\pgf@tempcolor{cmyk}{\pgf@cmykcolor}%
      \expandafter\pgf@set@fill@patternuncolored\pgf@cmykcolor\relax{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\def\pgf@set@fill@patternuncolored#1,#2,#3,#4\relax#5{%
  \pgfsys@setpatternuncolored{\csname pgf@pattern@name@#5\endcsname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\definecolor{myblack}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\draw[pattern = grid, pattern color = myblack] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,1); 

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

A call to ghostscript, such as

```
gs -q -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov <filename>.pdf
```

yields the following for this pdf:

```
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.59889 CMYK OK
```

All the above would seem to suggest that the issue has something to do with pgf, the conversions it does to rgb, and the subsequent cmyk properties inherited by the PDF.

**Note:** During my playing around with this, if we modify the `\draw` command to specify `draw=none` in the code provided in the question to suppress the black frame around the outside, namely

```
\draw[pattern = grid, pattern color = myblack, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,1);
```

then the output from ghostscript is as follows.

```
 0.53333  0.53333  0.53333  0.53333 CMYK OK
```

This suggests that the "black" colour being used to draw the gridlines has been stored as `cmyk(1,1,1,1)`, as opposed to `cmyk(0,0,0,1)`.

Comment: Rather than using the GhostScript inkcov device, my suggestion is to import your PDF in Scribus. You can then see which colours are used in the document and which objects are which colour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In the above example, I think it's clear where the colour is coming from, because the picture is a black grid on a white background, but I can imagine Scribus being very useful for this.

Comment: @rbignall actually adding the `draw=none` neither changes the GhostScript output for me nor changes the colours when I import into Scribus. All The lines are CMYK black. Though interestingly, Scribus adds RGB black to its list of used colours when importing these PDFs. But no objects actually seem to use the RGB Black.

Comment: @DavidPurton that's strange. I would at least expect the numbers to change, since `draw=none` means that there is, overall, less black on the page. The colours on the page are CMYK, the problem is the non-zero values for C, M and Y: this is enough to trigger professional printers to automatically print in colour.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit lazy in my language. The inkcov output changes to: `0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.53333 CMYK OK`, which is expected.

Comment: I have GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)

Comment: @DavidPurton Why doesn't change the draw=none the cmy values of your inkcov check? If I do this, I get similar results as rbrignall. My Ghostscript version is 9.21 but this shouldn't change anything?!?

Comment: @user206411. I do not know why I get different results to you both. But I can confirm that without the `draw=none` I get: `0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.59889 CMYK OK` and with the `draw=none` I get: `0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.53333 CMYK OK`. Perhaps a bug was recently fixed in GhostScript? My `tikz` version is 3.1.4b.

Comment: @DavidPurton ghostscript does nothing for me in either case, both version 9.50 and 9.26 (since I seem to have both on my machine).

Comment: (Also on tikz 3.1.4b).